# Field Formula to Count Contact Number of Cases

Tags: case, lookup, contact, related-list

I have done some researching and just trying to verify that this is not possible to count the number of cases a contact has created with a formula field. Is the only option a trigger? I'm assuming I then would need to mass update current contact records. Is this correct?

I can write a trigger if necessary and then write a bulk update class to implement, but would rather not do that if it's something possible with a formula.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with a trigger. If the relationship of Contact-Case were Master-Detail it would be possible with a rollup summary. But it isn't, so it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Whenever I think something in SF is going to be easy it's not. I'm surprised that this is not an out of the box feature. Anyhow, I ended up modifying an existing apex class and VF page I had that would check if the contact had created a case with SOQL. Once I have the list I add them to a campaign. We are using Pardot and were hoping to check a field for a value, so it's just one more step to add them to a campaign and use that for the Pardot list.